# Is there a VS code editor extension for displaying field-type icons on the side?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, icons

Is there a Visual Studio 2010/2013 extension which allows me to see icons of methods/properties/fields/etc. on the code editor's left side similar to SharpDevelop's feature?

I have searched the VS extensions gallery and on other parts of the Internet, but haven't found anything similar. I am asking here because maybe I have overlooked some other places.

[image: Sharp Develop feature]

Edit: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34eee02b-f1f6-433a-b210-62e94c0bcb87
is the closest thing I could find, but still not the same thing.

Comment: I think ReSharper gives you that feature (or possibility to set it up), but you might not consider it a extension... why don't use SharpDevelop?

Comment: I don't want to use SharpDevelop, I am just interested in that specific feature. I have researched the ReSharper documentation and I have not seen anything similar. If you know different, please show it explicitly, guessing doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is [CodeRush Member Icons](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument3528)